# How to use firebase data to navigate on and on in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image]

I learned how to navigate to other page and pop it but with the logic I drew up above, I have no idea how to do it. (I wasn't able to find something similar on internet). The comments in the images are created by users and once it is submitted, it is listed in ListView.builder using firebase. How do I make it that when user select 1 comment, it navigates to new page automatically that hasn't been created? Is it even possible? Thank you in advance

```
  body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                child: Text('Chapter 1'),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                        offset: Offset(4, 4),
                        blurRadius: 13,
                      ),
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        offset: Offset(-4, -4),
                        blurRadius: 13,
                      )
                    ]),
              ),            
              Container(
                  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: users,
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Something went wrong.');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Text('Loading');
                      }

                      final data = snapshot.requireData;

                      return ListView.builder(
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: data.size,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('${data.docs[index]['name']}\n${data.docs[index]['age']}');
                                },
                                title: Text('${data.docs[index]['name']}\n${data.docs[index]['age']}'),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    },
                  )
              ),
```

[image]

Here is an actual app for better understanding

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is useless. It's clear that you have a question about Firebase and Flutter, but there is no information about what that question might be. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a problem solution, and your current title provides no information at all. If you're posting here, we know you have a question. **What is that question?** should be the title.

Comment: I've edited my question title. Thanks for notifying me about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you displaying the details of list-tiles clicked by users on the container?
If so, you don't have to navigate to new page. You can just change the display section based on click.  Also, because when you go to new page it usually means item> item_detail, we don't display items list on new page.

Logic will be like

```
Column[DetailContainer, ListView(ListTiles)]
```

On List Click change Detail Container's content.

But If you want to change pages, then you should use Navigator 2.0 packages like go_router and state management like Provider.

Comment: Is there any examples I can look in to about it? I want to see how detailedcontainer and listview are used in real example

Comment: Create key for each listTiles, then create function that will pass correct information indentified by key to the detail container.